# Which files ubuntu watches by default

Tags: inotify

I am working with meteor js, when running `meteor` command (which builds up the web app), I got this output to the terminal:

```
  => It looks like a simple tweak to your system's configuration will make 
  many tools (including this Meteor command) more efficient. To learn more,
  see https://github.com/meteor/meteor/wiki/File-Change-Watcher-Efficiency
```

[There](https://github.com/meteor/docs/blob/version-NEXT/long-form/file-change-watcher-efficiency.md) it's said that the problem is with `inotify`:

> This message means that meteor tried to use the Linux inotify API to watch for file changes, but you've already reached the system-wide limit for the number of files that you can watch (probably in a different program entirely!).
>
> Fortunately, this is easy to fix. Just run this command at your shell, entering your password when prompted:

```
echo fs.inotify.max_user_watches=524288 | sudo tee -a /etc/sysctl.conf && sudo sysctl -p
```

Though a workaround is given, I am still curious to know **which files ubuntu (or `inotify`) is watching by default and where can I see that?**

I am using ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I think your question is mostly: "what is `inotify` and what does it do/how does it work?", correct?

Comment: Bad question - I should not have to follow a link to see which directions you followed - and "which directions" is not the informative part - tell us exactly what you did (often people mis-follow directions) and what messages you got.

Comment: @grooveplex I understand that `inotify` is the tool that watches the filesystem (getting how it work would be out of my league  for now). I would more like to know if there are any default applications on ubuntu that are using it.

Comment: @waltinator took notice of your comment and edited the question, I hope that now it is better. I am not searching for a solution, but to know which default applications are using `inotify` as well.